# Using services for constans list in backend or declare constants in front application

Tags: java, angular, rest

I want to know what is the best practice for application that use angular in FRONT and Rest in BACK.

I have an enumuration in the backend application, so in my front application I need to use select input from a list of choices that contain the Enumuration values.

What is the best practice to feed this list, do I need to use service in Backend app or just use Contants property that contain the Enumuration values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the list may change in the future, it is better to get it from database, not from constants in backend. That way if you need to modify the list, you can do it without having to re-deploy your application.

If you know it will NEVER change, and you only use it in the front, create the list in the front (that way you save yourself the trouble of data transferring). If both the service and the front end reference the list, declare it in the service and return it to the front end. That way, if you need to modify it, you only do it in one place.

Comment: Thank you for your response, yes the list is constant (just enumuration).so another question why not provide à service in the backend that return the list and consume it in frontend to feed a list variable

Comment: I edited my answer a bit to explain when you should declare it in the service

Comment: Okey know i understand that using service in the backend is more practical than declaring a constant in FE, cause in my case i think i will modify my list during the developpement

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the size of the list and if you should update it from time to time. 
If the enumeration is huge and you all-the time should update it - use another one endpoint and load it once when FE need it.

If it's still huge, but updates not so often - you can use endpoint and store it in the local storage of the browser.

If it's like 5 enumerations and nothing to update - just double it on FE

Comment: Thank you, so it's not recomended the use of contants variables in FE ?